# Как правильно передать массив аргументом для пользовательской функции

Tags: php

Если не брать в функцию все это, тогда результат работает. А если вот так в функции все выполнять, тогда PHP ругается:

> «Invalid argument supplied for foreach()»

Сделал вывод, что неправильно передаю массив как аргумент для своей пользовательской функции `resultBuyList()`:

```
$buyList = array(
        array('name' => 'Телевизор', 'price' => '400', 'quantity' => 1),
        array('name' => 'Телефон', 'price' => '300', 'quantity' => 3),
        array('name' => 'Кросовки', 'price' => '150', 'quantity' => 2),
    );

     function resultBuyList($buyList)
     {  
        foreach ($buyList  as $key => $value) { 
            $credits = $value['quantity'] * $value['price'];
            $creditCount += $credits;
            $productCount += $value['quantity'];
        }
         return $result = "Вы купили $productCount единиц товара, общая сумма к оплате: $creditCount";
    }


     resultBuyList($buyList);
```

Comment: Может вы просто иногда передаете массив, не содержащий в себе ничего? `foreach` таким сообщением ругается именно на это обычно. `А если вот так в функции все выполнять, тогда PHP ругается` - так это как? Лучше полностью написать как вы пытаетесь написать...именно так, как когда ругается

Comment: Вот этот код который я указал в вопросе я и хочу запустить. Когда запускаю, получаю эту ошибку с Invalid argument. Хочу узнать что я делаю не так и как сделать так, чтобы код работал.

Comment: именно тот код что в вопросе и именно в том виде что он есть - рабочий.... за исключением что не объявлены начальные значения для creditCount  и productCount

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь за то, что спорю, но уверяю вас, этот код (именно в том виде который есть) выдает ошибку «Invalid argument supplied for foreach()». Правда, попробуйте запустить — убедитесь в этом.

Comment: дык....... http://ideone.com/ZtJ6kP  =)

Comment: Что-то совершенно необычное произошло, ведь только что не работало, а теперь работает. Спасибо! Вот это да. Мне, наверное, отдохнуть нужно.

Comment: http://ideone.com/OLWW95 а теперь чудо. Мы передаем NULL в качестве аргумента и у нас вываливается ошибка.

Comment: @ArchDemon ну об этом я еще в самом начале сказал. То есть если например где-то из БД достается массив, то не факт что он достается и в результате выходит ошибка.......а если манипулировать именно этими данными - то всё рабочее

Answer (score 0):

```
function resultBuyList($buyList) { 

    if (!is_array($buyList) {
        return "Вы ничего не купили, но вам всё равно придется заплатить 1 000 000 рублей";
    }
    ...
}
```

И подобных ошибок не будет